# Which resistor value for MOSFET Gate

Tags: transistors, mosfet, resistors

I would like to replace the BC547 to [SM3119NAU](http://www.sinopowersemi.com/temp/SM3119NAU_datasheet.pdf) on this circuit. I have a several questions for this circuit.

1. Which resistor Rx value to choose?
2. Which resistor package to choose 0805 or 1206?

Due to the space on my PCB board, I have to use SMD components.

[image]

Comment: What circuit? Where is it?

Comment: You don't need resistors for MOSFETs. Might want to leave space though aand just use jumpers in case you do want to adjust timing though.

Comment: um, its recommended to include resistors, especially if it is PWM'ed

Comment: 10 ohms should be fine.

Comment: @DKNguyen The CD4017 does not have particularly strong output drive (about 2.5mA sourcing at 25C); a small resistor in the gate circuit would prevent stressing the outputs during both turn on and turn off as this MOSFET is a power device with significant gate charge.

Comment: exactly. plus you don't want to setup a pierce oscillator or cause additional emi considerations. for the sake of a 22R just to provide some damping and some limit on the current, why not